# Dual boot with different disks

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, partitioning

I have an desktop with SSD and I want to install and partition my recently bought 1TB HDD on it, but I have a few questions:

1. Because there's not much space left on my SSD, I would like to leave him alone with Windows. If I install Linux on the HDD, does grub detect the two different disks automatically?
2. I pretend to create a 150GB partition for Ubuntu on the HDD and leave the rest as NTFS. But, I want to be able to easily reinstall Ubuntu or install other distros on this partition, it's easy that way? I just need to format "/" partition and click on install?
3. When doing a clean reinstall of Linux, can I format the swap partition too?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You might want other partitions on the hdd (in addition to swap), maybe an EFI and even a grub-bios, depending upon the type of machine and the disk formatting.

Answer (score 0):

If you are planning to install and frequently reinstall [you do that with Windows? Not so common with Linux :))] Ubuntu, you wont have a problem with the second drive. But you might not want to do automatic partitioning. Although in the recent versions of the installer Ubuntu detects older installs and asks you what to do with it.

Installation on the second harddrive is no problem, just select it during the process. You can just reinstall afterwards and before you put anything else on that drive if you want to see how it works. Once you know what it does its easy to gain confidence :)

Just make sure you read the screens carefully when it comes to what drives and partitions to use.

If you can run virtual machines on your Windows try it in a virtual machine. Then you could even compare different distributions without the risk of breaking anything.